# Invoke a external python script from a html code

Tags: python, html

I have created a button in HTML , i want to invoke a external python script when that button is clicked.

and also pass on some variables into that python script if possible.

which method would be the simplest and fastest.
TIA

I tried flask but that didnt help me, my html code is being hosted on apache. i cannot / shouldn't (maybe) use flask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Flask, you can use Django. If you don't want to use Django either, you can use ajax to call the script as Fastnlight has shown above.

In case that does not work, you can use "py-script". It is like javascript. It is in experimental phase but can do simple tasks in your browser window.

link to pyscript: https://pyscript.net/

Comment: Thanks i went through pyscript ,  my python script involves creating a incident in SNOW , it didnt work.